# Polynomials of degree 2 sharing the same zero set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be an algebraically closed field, and let $f,g \in \mathbb{K}[X_{1},\dots,X_{n}]$ be polynomials of degree 2.

Is it true that $$\{\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{K}^{n} \colon f(\boldsymbol{x})=0\} = \{\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{K}^{n} \colon g(\boldsymbol{x})=0\}$$ only if $f = \rho g$ for some $\rho \in \mathbb{K}-\{0\}$?

I’m looking for either a proof or a counterexample. Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

I have tried to apply the Nullstellensatz, but I could only conclude that a power of $f$ belongs to $(g)$ - the ideal generated by $g$ - and that a power of $g$ belongs to $(f)$.

Comment: What are your thoughts/what have you tried? For example, this question would seem ripe for some reasoning using the Nullstellensatz - if you know $V(f)=V(g)$, then what can you say about $I(V(f))$ and $I(V(g))$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close to the answer. By the Nullstellensatz, we have that $\sqrt{(f)}=\sqrt{(g)}$. As $K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ is a UFD, this means that if we factor $f=u_1\prod f_i^{a_i}$ and $g=u_2\prod g_j^{b_j}$ as powers of irreducible elements with $u_1,u_2$ units, then we have that $\{f_i\}=\{g_j\}$ as sets. If these sets are both a single irreducible polynomial of degree 2, then $f=\alpha g$. If these sets are both a single irreducible polynomial of degree 1, say $h$, then $f=u_1h^2$ and $g=u_2h^2$, so $f=\alpha g$. If these sets are two distinct polynomials $r,s$ then $f=u_1rs$ and $g=u_2rs$, so $f=\alpha g$.

This is false as soon as one considers polynomials of degree 3 in this setting - consider $x^2y$ versus $xy^2$. If one keeps track of nilpotents, then one can distinguish these sorts of counterexamples.